# ipython notebook doesn't use custom css file

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use custom themes with my ipython notebooks. For this purpose I have first created a new profile:

```
C:\>ipython profile create teststyle
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'C:\\Users\\mayankpj\\.ipython\\profile_teststyle\\ipython_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'C:\\Users\\mayankpj\\.ipython\\profile_teststyle\\ipython_qtconsole_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'C:\\Users\\mayankpj\\.ipython\\profile_teststyle\\ipython_notebook_config.py'
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'C:\\Users\\mayankpj\\.ipython\\profile_teststyle\\ipython_nbconvert_config.py'
```

Then I have replaced the "C:\Users\mayankpj.ipython\profile_teststyle\static\custom\custom.css" file with the one from here: https://github.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook
I grabbed one of the css files and renamed it to custom.css and replaced the above file with it.

Now, I launched the ipython notebook session with the above profile:

```
C:\>ipython notebook --profile=teststyle
2014-12-16 04:11:44.407 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\\Users\\mayankpj\\.ipython\\profile_teststyle'
2014-12-16 04:11:44.500 [NotebookApp] Serving local MathJax from C:\Users\mayankpj\.ipython\nbextensions\mathjax\MathJax.js at /nbextensions/mathjax/M
athJax.js
2014-12-16 04:11:44.828 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\
2014-12-16 04:11:44.828 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2014-12-16 04:11:44.828 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2014-12-16 04:11:44.828 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

However, when i create a new notebook, it is same as earlier. I have updated my ipython to 2.3.0 and am using pythonxy distribution on windows 8. I have installed local copy of mathjax and pandoc on my machine and can export notebooks as html and rst files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I also tried incognito mode of browser but to no avail. Also, i looked at the js console, it had the following info:

```
 Default extension for cell metadata editing loaded.
rawcell.js:87 Raw Cell Format toolbar preset loaded.
slideshow.js:48 Slideshow extension for metadata editing loaded.
main.js:29 patching CM for undefined indent
kernel.js:124 Kernel started:  182e1a5b-8e4b-4993-a1ac-be2c97508e79
kernel.js:151 Starting WebSockets: ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/182e1a5b-8e4b-4993-a1ac-be2c97508e79
:8888/static/components/backbone/backbone-min.map:1 GET http://localhost:8888/static/components/backbone/backbone-min.map 404 (Not Found)
:8888/static/components/underscore/underscore-min.map:1 GET http://localhost:8888/static/components/underscore/underscore-min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Try incognito windows of, css is often agressively cached. Check also browser Javascript console.

Comment: I tried using the incognito mode, but didn't work. I pasted the console matter in the post above...

Comment: Hum, weird, what if you access `http://localhost:8888/static/custom/custom.css` directly ? Start `ipython notebook --debug` see if there is more interesting message (probably not) but you seem to have done everything right.  IPython 2.3 or above ?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!, I can reach the custom.css file alright, and the debug mode doesn't give any errors or any useful information. I am using Ipython 2.3.0 and I am using Pythonxy distribution, could that be a problem?